# Serial Ports/Tcp Server interferences

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets, tcp, serial-port

I've got a server which has two types of services: one provided by a TCP/IP server thread and another type provided by a number (variable) of serial peripherals; for the TCP/IP server I'm using the standard `System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener` object from the framework and for the serial peripherals I'm using the standard `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` object.

When I have one service up but the other down there's no problem and everything works fine, but when I need to use the two services together the TCP server starts to become unresponsive, getting only a few of the various messages it usually takes.

As a note, I've tried with Wireshark to sniff the underlying tcp traffic and as I wasn't suspecting, the tcp traffic is not even generated (or read by the LAN physical card); I don't understand what I need to do now.

Thanks everyone!

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.IO.Ports.SerialPort

Public Class Form1
Private WithEvents mSerial As System.IO.Ports.SerialPort
Private mTcpServer As System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener
Private tcpThread As Threading.Thread

Sub main() Handles Me.Load
    Open(1)
    Dim idAdd As IPAddress = IPAddress.Any
    mTcpServer = New TcpListener(idAdd, 41000)
    mTcpServer.Start()

    tcpThread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf TcpRollingThread)
    tcpThread.Start()

    tcpThread.Join()
End Sub

Private Sub TcpRollingThread()
    Do
        mTcpServer.AcceptTcpClient()
        Console.WriteLine("Tcp received")
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub dataReceived_handler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles mSerial.DataReceived
    Console.WriteLine("Serial bytes received: " + mSerial.BytesToRead.ToString())
End Sub

Public Function Open(ByVal port As Integer) As Boolean
    If port > 0 Then
        Try
            mSerial = New System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM" + port.ToString)
            With mSerial
                .BaudRate = 9600
                .DataBits = 8
                .StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
                .Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
                .ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1
                .Open()
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function

End Class
```

Here a portion of the code: when I'm expecting little data (e.g. 2-3 bytes) the connection arrives: when I'm expecting a little more (16 to 20 bytes) the connection doesn't show itself but I'm sure that in the other end it starts.

Comment: I'll be adding portions of the code monday; I'm sorry but it's not a little project, it's a hundred of classes project and I have to extrapolate the portions of code you may need

Comment: I've added the code, with some specific details, I don't understand why has been closed